# delete a line if it contain a particular match from a file in bash

Tags: bash, grep, sed

I have a file contain lines like the following.

```
10   TEST   NO   SOMETHING 
20   TEST   YES  SOMETHING 
101  TEST   YES  SOMETHING 
100  TEST   NO   SOMETHING
```

How can I delete only the line that has `10` at the beginning using sed or any other tool if I find a matching word `10`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed '/^10[^0-9]/d' file
```

If you want to edit file "in place", add sed's option `-i`.

---

```
grep -v '^10[^0-9]' file
```

Comment: Thank You very much... I will use the sed as i wanted.. @Cyrus